# Mathematics without the principle of unique choice

Tags: lo.logic, foundations, constructive-mathematics

The *principle of unique choice* (PUC), also called the *principle of function comprehension*, says that if $R$ is a relation between two sets $A,B$, and for every $x\in A$ there exists a *unique* $y\in B$ such that $R(x,y)$, then there exists a function $f:A\to B$ such that $R(x,f(x))$ for every $x\in A$.

In ZF set theory (without the *axiom* of choice) this principle is provable; indeed it is basically the *definition* of what it means to be a "function".  The same is true in weaker, e.g. intuitionistic set theories, and also for h-sets and h-relations in homotopy type theory / univalent foundations.  However, PUC is not provable in (classical or intuitionistic) higher-order logic (HOL) — unless we assert it, or something that implies it, as an additional axiom.

Moreover, there are naturally-arising models of HOL in which PUC fails.  For instance, we can take the types to be topological spaces, and the predicates on a space $A$ to be the *subspaces* of $A$ (subsets with the subspace topology); then a relation $R$ as in PUC corresponds to a span $A \leftarrow R \to B$ in which $R\to A$ is a continuous bijection, but need not have a continuous inverse enabling us to define a continuous map $A\to B$.  (To be more precise, it would be better to replace topological spaces by something slightly better-behaved, such as a quasitopos.)  We can also take the types to be partial equivalence relations on a partial combinatory algebra, or partial equivalence relations in a tripos.

Constructive mathematicians following Brouwer and Bishop have explored in depth what mathematics looks like in the absence of the full axiom of choice and the law of excluded middle.  Usually it's not much different; one just has to take extra care in various places and state various theorems in idiosyncratic ways.  Moreover, classical mathematics can be embedded in constructive mathematics, e.g. by judicious insertion of double-negations; thus constructive mathematics is simply "more informative", i.e. it "draws distinctions that classical mathematics ignores".

However, all constructive mathematicians that I know of accept the principle of unique choice.  Has anyone seriously explored what mathematics would look like in the absence of PUC?  I don't mean simply using the internal language of a quasitopos to prove a few things; I mean a serious development of large swaths of mathematics akin to Bishop's *Constructive analysis*.

Note that, as is the case with classical and constructive mathematics, ordinary mathematics with PUC should embed into mathematics without PUC by simply interpreting the word "function" to mean a total functional *relation* as appears in the hypothesis of PUC (which I call an *anafunction* after Makkai's "anafunctors").  So it seems that mathematics without PUC should again be simply "drawing previously-ignored distinctions", keeping track of which anafunctions are actually functions.

---

**Edit:** Frank Waaldijk's answer below points out that I should be more specific about what I mean by "mathematics without PUC", as there is actually more than one way that PUC could fail.  In this question I'm thinking about mathematics formalizable (though not necessarily actually formalized) in higher-order logic in one of two ways:

1. Define "sets" to be types equipped with equivalence relations (or partial equivalence relations), and "functions" to be maps between types ("operations") that preserve these equality relations.
2. Include "subtypes" and "quotient types" in the logic, and define "sets" to be simply types, and "functions" to be maps between them.

In either case there is also a natural notion of "anafunction", namely a binary relation that is total and functional, and PUC need not hold: not every anafunction is representable by a function.  By contrast, we can also formalize mathematics *with* PUC in HOL in either of these ways by defining a "function" to be such an "anafunction", i.e. a total functional binary relation.  For instance, this is what is done semantically in constructing a topos from a tripos.

Frank describes a different approach that is something akin to the following (also in HOL):

- Define a "set" to be a type equipped with both an equivalence relation of "equality" and a compatible binary relation of [inequality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/inequality+relation) or [apartness](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/apartness+relation), and define a "function" to be a *binary relation* between types that is total, functional, and reflects inequality (i.e. is "strongly extensional").

Here we appear to take the "anafunction" route by *defining* a "function" to be a total functional relation, but we also include "strong extensionality" in the definition of "function".  Now PUC fails because a total functional relation need not be strongly extensional.  This is also interesting, but it is not what I had in mind.

Of course, the two could be combined: we could define a function to be a map of types that is strongly extensional, so that a total functional relation could fail to be represented by a map of types *and* also fail to be strongly extensional.

**Edit 2:** Monroe Eskew points out in the comments yet another situation (again, not the one I'm asking about right now) where a version of PUC can fail, namely in ZF-type set theories without the replacement axiom.  In that case one can have a class-relation that is functional and whose domain is a set, but whose codomain is not a set, and hence which does not define a function (a function being required to be itself a set).

Comment: See perhaps Arnaud Spiwack’s PhD thesis: [Verified Computing in Homological Algebra](https://pastel.archives-ouvertes.fr/pastel-00605836).

Comment: Unique choice is absent from classical reverse maths. It possible that someone has also tried to remove it from constructive reverse maths, but I cannot currently find a precise reference.

Comment: Suppose we have some topos of smooth functions where $\forall x\in R\ \exists! y\in R\ x=y^3$ holds but there is no cube-root function because all functions are smooth.  It seems that whenever we would want such a function, we could just talk about the relation instead, and the resulting math might become an awkward but uninsightful variant of the usual.

Comment: @MattF. Yes, in the last paragraph of the question I mentioned that we can talk about anafunctions instead of functions to "recover ordinary math".  I suppose whether something is "insightful" is in the eye of the beholder -- Spiwack's thesis that Vej linked to considers the lack of PUC a virtue from a computational standpoint because an "effective" bijection can fail to have an "effective" inverse (e.g. a cryptographic hash function).  In your example, it seems that we would be keeping track of which functions are smooth, which is also useful.

Comment: So perhaps a good example is the topos of N with its polynomial-time functions.  Then we have a nice set of operations for generating such functions.  The topos verifies that one such function computes discrete exponentials in a bijective way.  And we can state in the internal language, though it may or may not be true, that no (polynomial-time) function computes discrete logarithms.

Comment: ...and people joke that I don't like the axiom of choice. I should show them this question! :)

Comment: I just noticed that https://mathoverflow.net/q/41208/49 and its related blog post http://math.andrej.com/2010/11/10/subgroups-are-equalizers-constructively/ are related to this question.

Comment: @BasSpitters Do you know a category-theoretic/type-theoretic exposition of reverse math?  At one point I was half-convinced that classical reverse math was something like the internal logic of the fibration of *complemented* subobjects in a non-Boolean Heyting category, which would fit it fairly neatly into this picture.

Comment: Milly Maietti and Giovanni Sambin studied absence of unique choice is some detail. You could write to Milly and ask here exactly where.

Comment: This sounds like asking what consonants I can form if I cut this section of my tongue.

Comment: @MikeShulman No, I am not aware of a connection between reverse math and category theory.

Comment: @MonroeEskew In 1927 Hilbert wrote "taking the principle of excluded middle from the mathematician would be the same, say, as proscribing the telescope to the astronomer or to the boxer the use of his fists."  But now we know that he was quite wrong; surprisingly little is lost from mathematics when you take away excluded middle, and there are good reasons to ask the question.  It pays to keep an open mind.

Comment: @MikeShulman: personally I think investigations of systems which fail to satisfy some elementary principle are probably not interesting from a foundational perspective. The example you give seems like it should be phrased in terms of collections of *continuous* functions. I don’t see the need to pretend that we live in a universe in which we use the general term “function” to refer to some much smaller class. But this is just opinion.

Comment: @MonroeEskew I don't know what you mean by a "foundational perspective", but from a *practical* perspective, internal languages of all sorts are, I think, undeniably useful.  Whether or not one believes the law of excluded middle to be "true", it is a fact that it fails in the internal language of general toposes, and that internal language is a useful tool when studying such toposes.  Even more basic logical laws like contraction and weakening fail in the internal languages of monoidal categories, yet the resulting "linear logics" are again a useful tool in their study.

Comment: So it is useful to know what mathematics looks like when done in the absence of various principles, even if one believes those principles to be "true" in an absolute sense, because it tells us how much of mathematics can be automatically internalized into various sorts of categories.

Comment: But it looks like you’re asking what if we redefine words so that elementary constructions fail. I would ask why? What’s the application?

Comment: @MonroeEskew I just told you: there are interesting categories in whose internal languages those elementary constructions *do* fail.

Comment: @MonroeEskew and MikeShulman: this reminds me of a similar disparaging remark that I made regarding a question that Martín Escardo posted on a constructive forum. He was kind enough to explain his perspective and its usefulness to me in detail... and my own interest in these questions has grown considerably since. It happens to me so very often that I have to revise my opinion once certain 'language barriers' have been removed...

Comment: @MikeShulman: With your specific unique choice question here, what application do you have in mind? Is there a problem you can solve by using the vocabulary in this way?

Comment: @MonroeEskew I do not have a specific problem in mind at this time.  My approach to mathematics is based on a quest for understanding rather than on trying to solve specific problems.  Following up analogies and looking for new applications of old ideas like this is often a fruitful way to produce theories and techniques that end up solving specific problems that one wouldn't have expected at the beginning.

Comment: (Which is not to disparage the importance of solving specific problems!  The two activities are synergistic; trying to solve a specific problem can also often lead to general insights that can then be abstracted and applied to new domains.)

Comment: (And, of course, in the course of conceptual work one may have to solve concrete problems, and I do solve concrete problems; I just meant that right now I am in the former mode.  Sorry, I didn't mean to wax overly philosophical, it's just that your last comment sounded like you might be implying that an investigation like this would only be worthwhile if it were motivated by trying to solve a specific problem.)

Comment: Let me explain my bias.  I work in set theory, and it's true that we often consider what is provable in fragments of something standard like ZFC.  However, we usually don't just do this for fun, but because we have to.  For example, we need to work in a small model like $H_\kappa$, which may not satisfy replacement.  Or when doing inner model theory, we may only have a model which satisfies replacement or separation for $\Sigma_n$ formulas.  We'd like to use our intuition about ordinary constructions, but sometimes we have to be careful.  Investigations of choiceless models...

Comment: ...are sometimes another matter, because AC has been historically controversial, so they are of interest from a foundations-of-math point of view.  But generally we want to work with models satisfying as much ordinary math as we can get in such-and-such context.  Otherwise it's pain without gain.

Comment: @MonroeEskew That doesn't sound too different to me from the pragmatic/categorical point of view I'm advocating here: we don't discard LEM or PUC for fun either, but because we have to, because we need to work in models (internal languages of categories) which may not satisfy them.

Comment: I know you said in the first line that $R$ is a relation between two *sets* but are you interested in situations where the range of $R$ is not a set?

Comment: @MonroeEskew In HOL every binary predicate has a pair of types as domain and codomain.  The codomain might not be a "set" (i.e. a type equipped with an equality relation), but in that case we can't talk about unique existence in order to phrase PUC.  The only other context I can think of in which one could consider "relations" whose codomain may not be a set is ZF-style set theory without replacement, where a class-relation could have a set as domain but not as codomain; is that what you have in mind?

Comment: Yes that’s right.

Comment: @MonroeEskew Then no, that's not what I'm interested in right now.  Are you suggesting that it could be regarded as a third way that "PUC" could fail?

Comment: Yes, it is a well-known context in which you have a definition of a function without a corresponding “function-as-object.”

Comment: Makes sense.  I've added another edit mentioning this.

Comment: I vaguely recall that some of Feferman's ideas about (predicative?) foundations involved requiring more constructivity for functions than for sets. Presumably that would make PUC fail. Unfortunately, I don't remember any details about this.

Answer (score 7):

You ask: Has anyone seriously explored what mathematics would look like in the absence of PUC?

Actually, I believe I have done so in my PhD thesis [modern intuitionistic topology](http://www.fwaaldijk.nl/modern%20intuitionistic%20topology.pdf). Don't let the title mislead you: more than half of the thesis is actually directly acceptable in BISH, and these results are all marked with an asterisk.

In my thesis, I define 'function' precisely according to what you describe, which is the ZF-definition. I have always considered this set-theoretic approach very convenient for a fundamental reunion of Bishop's and Brouwer's perspective. The usual dictum that BISH is a common core of INT and CLASS is actually untrue, since much of Bishop's definitions are too vague and therefore unacceptable in INT. But they can be naturally interpreted when using the ZF-definition, which I adopted in my thesis.

In my thesis, pretty large samples of constructive math are developed using this definition. (I would not call it large swaths, but I do not see any obstruction to expand these samples to large swaths). I can't recall even one instance where PUC would help one to prove more than what can be proven using the ZF-definition.

Just an example: the Dugundji Extension Theorem is proved in this way in chapter three.

Of course, I do use restricted forms of countable choice and dependent choice in my thesis. But that seems a separate issue from what you are asking.

To then specialize to INT or RUSS (recursive mathematics), I found (and find) it very convenient to define special functions, such as spread-functions and computable functions. One shows that these special functions indeed also specify functions (ZF-style), and then one can prove additional INT or RUSS results using either INT or RUSS choice axioms.

So I'm fairly confident in my answer that yes, large parts of constructive mathematics can be developed without PUC.

**Update** to reflect the comments below:

In my thesis the definition of function (0.1.3) essentially runs like this:

Let $(X,\#_1), (Y,\#_2)$ be apartness spaces, then $f\subset X\times Y$ is called a function iff:

(i) $\forall x\in X\ \exists y\in Y\ [\,(x,y)\in f\,]$

(ii) $\forall x,w\in X\ \forall y,z\in Y\ [\,((x,y)\in f\wedge(w,z)\in f\wedge y\#_2 z) \rightarrow x\#_1 w\,]\,$

With this definition of function, large samples of constructive math are developed, like I said. This does not require any form of PUC, and it is debatable whether PUC even holds in general with this definition.

That depends on how literal one wants to interpret PUC, and whether one wishes to include equivalence/apartness relations which are not the 'simple' Baire space equivalence/apartness.

But even to say that with this definition PUC holds for Baire space, is to interpret the quantifier $\exists!$ in a very specific way. Because one cannot derive (ii) from the usual interpretation of $\forall x \exists! y$.

**Second update** to reflect further comments below:

First I would like to recommend the OP's paper [Linear logic for constructive mathematics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.07518). I find it well written and it gives a promising (meta-)insight how to resolve annoying deficiencies of constructive logic, especially when constructivizing classical definitions.

Second, let me repeat that the above definition of function is far from the usual one in BISH (which is very vague!, see chptr. 2 def. 1.1 of *Constructive Analysis* [Bishop&Bridges1985]). It therefore stands alone in BISH, and it is not a trivial result that with this definition large parts of BISH can be developed.

Moreover, in BISH there is a real necessity for PUC as an axiom, since it does not follow at all from the definition of function and the other axioms. I give the following quotes (page 12, chptr. 1 'A constructivist manifesto' written in 1967):

> A choice function exists in constructive mathematics, because a choice
>   is implied by the very meaning of existence.

And a later addendum (1985) by Bridges (page 13, chptr 1. Notes):

> At first sight, Bishop' remark, "A choice function exists in constructive mathematics, because a choice is implied by the very meaning
>   of existence", appears to be contradicted by counterexamples of the
>   sort discussed in connection with the least-upper-bound principle. In
>   fact, there is no contradiction here. To see this, consider a
>   paraphrase of Bishop's remark: if to each $x$ in a set $A$ there
>   corresponds an element $y$ of a set $B$ such that a given property $P(x, y)$
>   holds, then it is implied by the very meaning of existence in
>   constructive mathematics that there is a finite routine for computing
>   an appropriate $y \in B$ from a given $x \in A$; although this routine may
>   not be a function relative to the given equality relation on $A$, it is
>   a function relative to the equality relation of identity (intensional
>   equality) on A, in which two elements are equal if and only if they
>   are given as identically the same object.

With the relational definition given in my thesis, there is no need for PUC as an axiom, like I said. And this remains so even if one interprets the quantifier $\exists!$ in such a way that PUC is validated for the natural apartness on Baire space. This natural apartness is not an extra structure, but the intuitionistic (and constructive!) way of handling equality. It corresponds rather precisely I believe to the linear-logic way of defining inequality (in the OP's paper mentioned above).

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying; the ZF-definition of function makes PUC true by definition.

Comment: I was probably too brief, I will expand a bit more in an update.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I don't really think the question of whether all functions should be assumed strongly extensional is much related to PUC, though.  In particular, in intuitionistic logic the presence of an apartness relation is extra structure on a set, and so a notion like "strongly extensional" which depends on such structure can't sensibly appear in a foundational principle like PUC.

Comment: By contrast, in the linear logic of https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.07518, inequality relations on every set are "built into the logic", but in this case they are also built into the notion of "unique existence", so that PUC can hold (but doesn't have to).

Comment: Hm, now I don't understand! Your comment strongly suggests that you already believe so much in PUC, that you feel a relation which satisfies PUC should be called a function (I disagree). And from there, that what I call a function should be called a 'strongly extensional' function... I think it would be clearer if you could phrase your question a  bit differently, because I feel I gave a perfectly correct answer which just doesn't happen to be in the direction which you were expecting... Well, I don't really mind, but it might help someone to come up with the answer you're looking for :-)

Comment: I also disagree that the Baire space (natural) apartness is an extra structure. It is in fact the intuitionistic (and constructive) way of handling equality. It corresponds rather precisely I would say with the linear logic inequality that you mention. And I also already mentioned that with definitions as given in my thesis, PUC can hold with a different interpretation of $\exists!$. But as you know I'm enthusiastic about your linear logic paper, so I'll try to sum all this up in a fair second update.

Comment: Hmm... maybe I understand better now what you are getting at: PUC could fail in other ways than the one I had in mind.  I'll update the question to clarify what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 6):

Posting on behalf of Milli Maietti.

A foundation for constructive mathematics  without unique choice is the Minimalist Foundation (MF) ideated in

[Maietti, Sambin, *Towards a minimalist foundation for constructive mathematics*](https://www.math.unipd.it/%7Emaietti/papers/MaiettiSambin-rev2.pdf)

and completed in

[Maietti, *A minimalist two-level foundation for constructive mathematics*](https://www.math.unipd.it/%7Emaietti/papers/tt.pdf)

This is meant as a  base system to formalize constructive point-free topology and perform constructive reverse mathematics,
where

- Dedekind reals  and Cauchy reals  defined in terms of functional relations do not form a set

(only Cauchy type-theoretic reals do form a set),
even in the *classical extension* of MF with excluded middle
as explained in

[Maietti, Sambin, *Why topology in the minimalist foundation must be pointfree*](https://www.math.unipd.it/%7Emaietti/papers/whyp.pdf)

A quotient completion of a tripos which does not impose unique choice has been introduced in

[Maietti, Rosolini, *Quotient completion for the foundation of constructive mathematics*](https://www.math.unipd.it/%7Emaietti/papers/quLU.pdf)

as a generalization of the ex/lex completion.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure whether [Yannick Forster](https://yforster.github.io) is hanging out around here, so allow me to refer you to his PhD thesis and his recent research.

Yannick uses the following setup to carry out synthetic computability theory (see his home page to get a feel for how much computability theory he handles):

- calculus of inductive constructions
- a `Prop` with excluded middle
- a form of Church's thesis "all functions are computable"

At first sight this looks contradictory because Church's thesis and excluded middle together produce a contradiction, as we can diagonalize to produce a non-computable function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$:

$$
f(n) =
\begin{cases}
k + 1 & \text{if $n$-th computable function outputs $k$ on input $n$}\\
42 \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Now, $f$ is total by excluded middle, hence there is some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f$ is the $m$-th computable function, but then we get $f(m) = f(m) + 1$.

Actually, the above proof secretly used unique choice. When we write down the definition of $f$ carefully, we notice that we actually gave the graph of $f$:
$$F(n,k) \iff
(\text{$n$-th machine on input $n$ outputs $k$}) \lor
((\text{$n$-th machine on input $n$ diverges}) \land k = 42)
$$

Luckily, unique choice is not validated by the calculus of inductive constructions.

Answer (score 3):

In a Bishop setting without any form of choice, while PUC does not hold generally, there are codomains for which it is provable, in a way that perhaps feels trivial. For the simplest example I can think of, given some set $B$ (equipped with an equality relation), consider the set of singleton subsets of $B$, $$S(B) := \{ X \in \mathscr{P}(B) \mid X \text{ inhabited and } x = y \text{ for all } x,y \in X\},$$
with equality just the usual equality of subsets ($X = Y$ when $x \in X$ iff $x \in Y$). Now, given a total functional relation $R$ over $A \times S(B)$, we can define $f:A \to S(B)$ by $$ f(a) := \{ b \in B \mid \text{for all } Y \in S(B),
 R(a, Y) \text{ implies } b \in Y \}.$$ It is not difficult to show (1) $f(a) \in S(B)$ for $a \in A$, (2) $R(a,Y)$ implies $Y = f(a)$ for $a \in A$, $Y \in S(B)$, (3) $R(a,f(a))$ for $a \in A$, and (4) $f$ respects equality on $A$. That proves PUC for codomain $S(B)$.

This is of course not magic, since we still need a choice function to recover anything from an element of $S(B)$. In a sense, we've just "flattened" two applications of choice into one.

You may well ask why you'd ever want to use this particular codomain, since it's basically just the classical definition of equivalence classes, avoiding which was the whole point of Bishop's idea of sets equipped with equality relations. Well, for basically the same reason as for $S(B)$, PUC is provable for the codomain of the Dedekind reals.

Another example of a codomain for which PUC is provable is Richman's construction of the completion of a metric space $X$ as a subset of $\mathbb{Q}^{+} \to \mathscr{P}(X)$ satisfying Cauchy-like criteria [1]. It's notable that Richman's motivation for the construction was to avoid (countable/dependent) choice. (I've also seen this construction referred to as Cauchy approximations.) I would argue that the "best" definition of metric completion is the terminal object of an appropriate category (specifically, the objects under a metric space $X$ in the category of dense isometries). If you accept that, then it follows that PUC is provable when the codomain is a metric completion, at least in this foundational setting (since Richman's construction has the corresponding universal property).

So, at least in this foundational setting, large swaths of mathematics (particularly analysis) remain unchanged without PUC, since it is simply provable (in perhaps an unsatisfying way) for many codomains of interest, particularly the reals and any other complete metric space.

[1] *Richman, Fred*, [**Real numbers and other completions**](https://doi.org/10.1002/malq.200710024), Math. Log. Q. 54, No. 1, 98-108 (2008). [ZBL1134.03041](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1134.03041).

Comment: This is a good point.  In tripos-theoretic language, these are the "weakly complete" sets.  The absence of PUC seems only to matter for "predicative" sets whose construction doesn't involve powersets, such as $\mathbb{N},\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q}$, and the ordinary Cauchy reals.  And I wouldn't be surprised if PUC also held automatically, at least in some contexts, for sets like $\mathbb{N},\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q}$ that can be defined without any quotients, i.e. such that their setoid equality is Leibniz equality.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than giving an answer, I decided to include a description of how exactly is $\exists!$ reflected in topos-theoretic context and how does it give meaning to the slogan "unique existence implies global existence". The oldest text I've seen where this occurs is Freyd's "[Aspects of topoi](https://ncatlab.org/spahn/files/aspects_of_topoi.pdf)" (Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. **7** (1972) 1--76, Proposition 2.21 on page 22)

For $f:X\to Y$, let $i_f:Q_f\rightarrowtail X$ be the equalizer of the singleton map $\{\_\}:X\to\mathscr PX$ with the composite
$$
X\xrightarrow fY\xrightarrow{f^{-1}}\mathscr PX
$$
where $\mathscr PX$ is the powerset, $\{\_\}$ is the transpose of the equality $X\times X\to\mathscr P1$ (classifying the diagonal $(1_X,1_X):X\rightarrowtail X\times X$) while $f^{-1}:Y\to\mathscr PX$ is the transpose of the map $X\times Y\to\mathscr P1$ classifying the graph $(1_X,f):X\rightarrowtail X\times Y$ of $f$.

Then it can be proved that this $i_f:Q_f\rightarrowtail X$ enjoys the following universal property: the square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    Q_f @>i_f>> X\\
    @| @VV f V\\
    Q_f @>f\circ i_f>> Y
\end{CD}
is pullback, and for any other pullback square
\begin{CD}
    Q@>g>> X\\
    @| @VVfV\\
    Q @>f\circ g>> Y
\end{CD}
the map $f\circ g:Q\to Y$ factors through $f\circ i_f:Q_f\to Y$.

It thus solves the problem of finding the "largest" $g:Q\to Y$ such that $g^*(f):X\times_YQ\to Q$ is an isomorphism.

The main reason I decided to mention this is that it raises natural questions - (a) whether having such "UE pullbacks" (that is, the ones with the above universal property) is the correct reexpression of the PUE in categorical semantics, and (b) whether the full topos structure is implied by having them. I doubt this last one, actually.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not distinguish between classical or constructive math, so I will provide an answer for the former.

*Has anyone seriously explored what mathematics would look like in the absence of PUC?*

In [1, 2] below, Dag Normann and I show that the following are equivalent in Kohlenbach's higher-order RM ([0)), where item (o) is a weak fragment of PUC.  Here,
*strongly countable* means that there is a bijection from the set to $\mathbb{N}$.

o) For $Y^2$, $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})(\exists! f \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}})(Y(f, n)=0 )$ implies $(\exists g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N})(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})(Y(g(n), n)=0) $.

a) every strongly countable set $A\subset [0, 1]$ can be enumerated.

b) every strongly countable set in $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ has a supremum.

c) and many more

As you can see, mathematics without PUC would look mighty strange, even classically.

**References**

[0] U. Kohlenbach Higher order reverse mathematics, Reverse mathematics 2001, Lect. Notes Log., vol. 21, ASL, 2005, pp. 281–295.

[1] D. Normann and S. Sanders, On robust thms due to Cantor, Weierstrass, and Heine-Borel, Submitted, arxiv:  https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.04787

[2] S. Sanders. Countable sets versus sets that are countable, Submitted, https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.01772