# Principle of unique choice in homotopy type theory

Tags: lo.logic, foundations, constructive-mathematics, homotopy-type-theory

In the MathOverflow thread [Mathematics without the principle of unique choice](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302037/mathematics-without-the-principle-of-unique-choice), Mike Shulman defines the principle of unique choice to be

> if $R$ is a relation between two sets $A$, $B$, and for every $x \in A$ there exists a unique $y \in B$ such that $R(x, y)$, then there exists a function $f:A \to B$ such that $R(x, f(x))$ for every $x \in A$.

Translated to homotopy type theory with the axiom of propositional resizing, where for all universes the type of all propositions in the universe is equivalent to the type of propositions in the base universe $\mathrm{Prop}$, the principle of unique choice then states:

> For every set $A$ and $B$ in a universe $\mathcal{U}$ and every relation $R$ between $A$ and $B$, if for every term $x:A$ the type [of all terms $y:B$ such that $R(x, y)$ is contractible] is contractible, then there merely exists a function $f:A \to B$ such that for every term $x:A$ the proposition $R(x, f(x))$ is contractible.

$$\prod_{A:\mathrm{Set}_\mathcal{U}} \prod_{B:\mathrm{Set}_\mathcal{U}} \prod_{R:A \times B \to \mathrm{Prop}} \left(\prod_{x:A} \mathrm{isContr}\left(\sum_{y:B} \mathrm{isContr}(R(x, y))\right)\right) \to \left\lVert \sum_{f:A \to B} \prod_{x:A} \mathrm{isContr}(R(x, f(x)) \right\rVert.$$

The thread above claims that this is provable in homotopy type theory.

1. How would one go about proving the principle of unique choice with propositional resizing?
2. If possible, how would one define the principle of unique choice without the axiom of propositional resizing, where the type of propositions could belong to any universe, and prove that it holds in homotopy type theory?

Comment: Without propositional resizing, unique choice is a scheme over the universe level of the relation $R$. (It is in any case a scheme over the universe levels of the types (they don't have to be sets!) $A$ and $B$.) Your version follows from the stronger principle, given types $A$ and $B$ and a (proposition-valued) relation $R$: $(\prod_{x:A}\mathrm{isContr}(\sum_{y:B}R(x,y))) \to \sum_{f:A\to B}\prod_{x:A}R(x,f(x))$ given by taken the center of contraction.